# Arcgis Javascript Api Identity Manager with proxy

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, arcgis-web-adaptor

I'm trying to setup an authentication architecture with a web app using [arcgis Javascript api](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) with a [configured .NET proxy](https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy) and a web adaptor.

When i load my app the identity manager shows up for locked resources.

1. Do i really need the proxy?
2. Why identity manager shows up on every page refresh when the validity is 60 minutes?

proxy.config

```
<ProxyConfig allowedReferers="*" logFile="proxylog.txt" mustMatch="false">

    <serverUrls>

        <serverUrl url = "http://arcgiserver.com/"
            matchAll="true"
            tokenServicesUri="http://arcgiserver.com/my_web_adaptor/tokens"
        />

    </serverUrls>
</ProxyConfig>
```

Comment: Did you add in a [new serverUrl](https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy#proxy-configuration-settings) for your resource?

Comment: Yes i added a server URL. I update the question with my proxy.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When it comes to secure services, proxies are typically used to authenticate on behalf of end users so that they are not forced to provide their own credentials at all.
2. by default, the identity manager doesn't write any cookies to local storage, so refreshing the page requires that the end user sign in again.  you can find an example application which demonstrates how to save sign-in information locally [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_identitymanager_client_side.html).